# sql SUM on specific date as user input and return the result in variable before print out the result

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sum

May I know how to I implement a `SUM amount` on my current sql code?

I tried Google around but it doesn't seems to have the answer I want. Most of them are MySQL format which is totally different with my current code where it is using PDO library.

My code:

```
try {
  $start_date = "3/1/2014";
  $end_date = "4/1/2014";
  $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $start_date);
  $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $end_date);
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE DATE(log_datetime) >= :start AND DATE(log_datetime) < :end + INTERVAL 1 DAY");
  $success = $query->execute(array(':start'=>$start->format('Y-m-d'), ':end'=>$end->format('Y-m-d')));

}
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

//result
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $log_id         = $row->log_id;
    $dob            = $row->dob;
    $log_datetime   = $row->log_datetime;
    $log_count      = $row->log_count;
    $amount         = $row->amount;

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($log_id) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($dob) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($log_datetime) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($log_count) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($amount) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fa8f/5

I want to `sum 'log_count'` and return the total of people visit on the date that user input and `sum amount` and return the value of earning on that specific date.

How do I do it in PHP PDO?

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I'm not a php programmer but if I wanted to get a sum, I wouldn't be selecting *.

Comment: @DanBracuk I know the select is to query the database before returning result, I guess I need to add a line of SUM, but I still couldn't figure out how to do it correctly

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with PDO. Please show the exact table schema, sample data and desired output.

Comment: You know that you can select the sum from the database I trust.  If you didn't, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: @peterm added sqlfiddle, as you can see my current code return the result on specific date, I need to know how to sum `log_count` and `amount` and return them into variable so I can echo out them separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You can just calculate your sums while you iterate over the resultset. Something like this

```sql
echo '<table><tbody>';
$log_count_total = 0;
$amount_total = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $log_count_total += $row->log_count;
    $amount_total += $row->amount;

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->log_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->dob . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->log_datetime . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->log_count . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->amount . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td></td><td></td><td></td>';
echo '<td><strong>' . $log_count_total . '</strong></td>';
echo '<td><strong>' . $amount_total . '</strong></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Output:

```
4    1956-05-15    2014-01-03 20:37:27    1    10
5    1940-07-31    2014-01-03 21:37:27    1    10
6    2000-02-18    2014-01-04 18:30:27    1    10
7    1955-08-31    2014-01-04 19:32:27    1    10
8    1983-11-22    2014-01-04 20:31:27    1    10
9    1958-08-09    2014-01-04 21:05:27    1    10
                                          6    60
```

---

If you need to get totals in one go

```sql
SELECT SUM(log_count) total_log_count, SUM(amount) total_amount
  FROM log 
 WHERE log_datetime >= '2014-01-03' 
   AND log_datetime <  '2014-01-04' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

**BTW:** Don't apply `DATE()` function to `log_datetime` in `WHERE` clause. Not only it's useless in this case but also invalidates the usage of any index you may have on that column effectively causing a full scan.

Output:

```
| TOTAL_LOG_COUNT | TOTAL_AMOUNT |
|-----------------|--------------|
|               6 |           60 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fa8f/7)** demo

Comment: yes I know how to do this, but do I do it in my current code and print out the result? as my concern now is how to print out the result with my current code

Comment: What is the problem with printing the results out? Do you want to print the details and the totals or something else? Can you show what is your expected output?

Comment: I need to implement with my current code. How do I add this row to my current code so it doesn't conflict with other result and print out the result of `total_log_count` and `total_amount`

Comment: Then you don't need additional query. You just calculate your sums while you're iterating over the resultset. See updated answer

Comment: You're quite welcome :) Don't forget to ditch `DATE()`s in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: actually I use DATE() it is because the data is using DATETIME format besides that, actually I having a problem with `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` as you see my query code, if without `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` it only return the data until `2014-01-03` if I add `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` in, it only can return me the data until today which is `2014-01-04` any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Again you **don't need** it. Your conditions are formed in a time-component safe manner.

Comment: Take a close look at this **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b84c9/2) example**

Comment: @perterm see the current **[link](http://http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b84c9/5)** why does the `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` make the result totally different?

Comment: It's because of `log_datetime <  '2014-01-04'`. It's less than, not less than or equal to. And it's exactly why you need to use `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` to be able to fetch all rows with time value less than the midnight of the next day. And it's **the proper way** to go.

Comment: now I get it, so I should change the `<` to `=` so that it will query the correct answer as I want. thank you so much for your effort! too bad I got less than 15 rep, if no I definately upvote your answer

Comment: Don't change `<`. If you need the data for one day only you just pass the same date as start and end. Again see my sqlfiddle.

Comment: thanks @peterm, last, do I need to remove out `=` from `>= 2014-01-03`? by the way, upvoted your answer and vote several usefull answer. besides that, do you mind to be my mentor? :)

Comment: No you don't want to remove `=` from left boundary condition, because you want to match anything that is greater than or **equal to the midnight** of this day. Suppose you have a record with `2013-01-03 00:00:00` if you drop `=` then you'll miss that record.

Comment: need your help again, as per [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d22b/13) I try to tweak around to get today report but it seems `NOW()` is like not working. I need to prepare the query by `today` `yesterday` `this week` this month` `last month` `this year` `last year` but I seems couldn't get the today day correctly... please advise

Comment: Sure. Can you post it as a new question? Other SO members or I will be happy to help you. If you wish you can then post a link to it here.

Comment: For a good example of the problems with an inclusive upper-bound on these kinds of ranges, [read this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  SQL Server has some additional issues, but this applies to essentially all RDBMSs (since most allow you to specify the precision of timestamp columns).  Note that the same issue applies to columns with similar concepts in ranges - dollar amounts, distances; essentially, all measurements, and anything not an integer count.